# PowerBI Scatter chart from excel

Tags: excel, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

i'm new with Power BI and i would like to aks you, how i make this "scatter"-chart from excel in power bi. My other problem is that my data doesn't look like this example. It's over more tables spreaded. Is it okay to combine tables and cheat my excel table, so i can do this diagram?

Thanks for your Help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNtUe.png)

I would like to find a good maintainable solution and I'm not sure if this is a good one, because of the many joins and merges I did in Power Query Editor

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.